# How to create my_Controller in sub directory for core and library in Codeigniter3?

Tags: codeigniter

How to create my_Controller in sub directory for core and library in Codeigniter?
I want to create sub director for admin pages using Codeigniter3
as below requirement.

Controller/admin/Admin_C **(Exstend Admin_Controller)** 1

Library/admin/Admin_Controller **(extends Cadmin_Controller)** 2

Core/admin/Cadmin_Controller **(extends CI_Controllers)** 3

**Problem**   `Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Controller' not found in D:\My data\project\wamp\www\Cootel\application\controllers\admin\Admin_C.php on line 3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant implement controller like that. All controller should be in controller folder(no sub-folders are used in there).

So your controller should come(file structurer)

1. controller

   - Admin_C

and in side `Admin_C`

```
class Admin_C extends CI_Controller//Admin_Controller should come as CI_Controller
{

}
```

If you using sub-folders you need to use `routing as well

And i **cant understand** what is your purpose with using this.

```
Library/admin/Admin_Controller
Core/admin/Cadmin_Controller
```

Comment: If i put all my Controller in the same position of Controller director my source will messy because I have alot controller and i want to store it by folder easy to implementation

Comment: so what is the purpose of `Library/admin/Admin_Controller` and `Core/admin/Cadmin_Controller` ??

Comment: Have another purpose because I want to do some feature before another controller inside of Admin_Controller loaded.and easy for me for placing some function in Admin_Controller and try to call from another related Controller